# Don't understand cause of this "index out of range" error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I know it is a simple question but I cant seem to figure out why it give me this error.

```
import datetime,openpyxl,re
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("..\\test.xlsx")
print(wb.sheetnames)
sh = wb["July"]
def values():
    for counter in range(0,104):
        results=[""]
        for row in sh["B3":"I16"]:
            #print("\n")
            for cell in row:
                b = cell.value
                #print(b)
                #if b == "None":
                #   break
                #else:
                result = re.sub("[0-9]+","", str(b))
                result = re.sub(r'[£]',"",result)
                results[counter] = result
                if(results[counter] == "Room"
                   or results[counter] == "None"
                   or results[counter] == "****"
                   or results[counter] == "Double Bed"):
                    None
                else:
                    print(results[counter])
                    #result1 = result
                    #print(result,result1)
```

and my error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Automated Email\Test\Test.py", line 26, in <module>
    values()   File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Automated Email\Test\Test.py", line 19, in values
    results[counter] = result

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What this program is meant to do is to pull some data from this test `xlsx` file and display them. after them I get the name only (not the price or signs) from the file and I separate some other empty cells after that I want to put them in an array so I can compare it to the previous values and if they are the same only print it once.

Comment: An `IndexError` in `results[counter]` means that `counter` is not a valid index for `results`. That may happen if `counter` is greater than the size of `results`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the index `counter` in your array `results` but this address is not part of your array yet. you have to `append` your value to add it to the array:

```py
results.append(result) #adds the value `result` to your array at a new index
if results[counter] == "Room" or results[counter] == "None" or results[counter] == "****" or results[counter] == "Double Bed":
   None
```

Comment: it didnt seemed like it worked i am not getting any output now compared to before where I was getting the names

Answer (score 0):

**Your variable results is a list (not a dictionary).**

You can only append to your list or replace existing values with their indeces.

When you execute the above code the counter index is not given. You can either add a next index with

```py
restults.append(result)
```

Or you can change

```py
results=[]
```

to

```py
results={}
```

Which makes it a dictionary. Here the index neither has to be a number nor has to be strictly incremented.

If you don't need the explicit int of the counter use the append-method.

Comment: I have tried both methods I couldn't get it to work I dont think it need to be a dictionary since it reads the cell as one value and I strip the value so its only name that gets displayed and I need to place that name in a list (all of the names in a list) so I can compare it to each other(also I forgot to mention that I was getting output of the names and that error)